# Download or Forward a PDF from Google Drive iPhone app

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, iphone

How do I forward or download a PDF from the Google Drive iPhone application?

Comment: The mobile website lets you forward a PDF via email. So that is what I ended up doing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a native iOS app. Such questions should be directed to [apple.se].

Answer (score 3):

Forwarding a PDF file via email or SMS may **not** be directly possible in Google Drive.  The GD iOS app has a "Share" option so you can email *a link* to that file, but not the file itself.  In Google Drive.app, click the right-arrow (greater-than symbol) to the right of the file name.  This shows the file's "Details" with a preview and so on.  Now click the "share this" link in the upper-right corner of the app, and choose "Share".

iOS doesn't really have the concept of "downloading", at least not in the general way it does in a desktop operating system.  iOS users can open compatible documents in apps that announce themselves in an "Open in..." list.  For example, when you click on the .PDF file name in Google Drive, the file viewer displays the file, and you can then "Open in..." a different PDF reading app.  If, for example, you choose to Open in... "Dropbox.app", you're able to both save the .PDF file into Dropbox, so it's available elsewhere, AND display the file.  Dropbox's file viewer *DOES* allow you to share the file via email or SMS.

Comment: It doesn't offer me the the "Open in..." bit

Answer (score 1):

I use a Mac. I figuratively "printed" my pdf file and saved it as a .pdf file.  It opened in Preview and I was able to save it to my desktop.

Comment: Yeah, except the OP was asking how to do this from an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

### It is now possible (Dec 29, 2016) in conjunction with other apps

1. On my iPhone 6 with iOS 10.2, I open Google Drive and navigate to a PDF that I have uploaded there.
2. Instead of clicking the title of the PDF to open it, I click the 3 dots on the right to pop open a menu.
3. Click "Send a copy".
4. In the bottom right of my screen, I click "Open in".
5. It then says "Preparing to export". Then I'm allowed to click "Import with FileApp".  [FileApp is a free app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fileapp-file-manager-document/id297804694?mt=8) that can store and display PDFs.
6. You can use that or some other similar app to import (i.e. download) the PDF to your phone and then forward it via email or message to someone else.